# Game Center Leaderboard is only showing current player's score

Tags: game-center, leaderboard, game-center-leaderboard

I tried posting this on the Apple Dev Forums, but I get an error message there.

I have a game up on the App Store that I developed:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/trading-day/id973564365?mt=8‌

Players are reporting that they can only see their individual scores on the Game Center leaderboard. The settings for the leaderboard that I created are really simple, and I don't understand how to make a normal leaderboard that shows all player scores.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I've having this same issue :( :( :(  https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/eggtastic-easter-egg-hunt/id1223565862 Did you figure anything out?